# Exception : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-cardview

I am using `CardView` of support library in my android app. I tried 4-5 hours to resolve this but i could not get success.

I have added `CardView` as a library in my project & v7 appcompat also

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp" >
```

But my app is crashing with below logs

```
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666): Process: com.xyzladdoo, PID: 5666
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at com.xyzladdoo.adapters.RecycleViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecycleViewAdapter.java:85)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at com.xyzladdoo.adapters.RecycleViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecycleViewAdapter.java:1)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:2915)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:2511)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$RenderState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1425)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:999)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:524)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1461)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:1600)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:543)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1594)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:887)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2013)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1770)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
10-31 18:41:39.577: E/AndroidRuntime(5666):     at an
```

Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this link please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449344/using-android-support-v7-widget-cardview-in-my-project-eclipse

Comment: is that your xml?, post more of it, and also your inflate.

Comment: @FaroukTouzi i am using adt

Comment: add  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" line

Comment: Is the CardView your top-level XML element?

Comment: @Prag'sシ it is already there please see in my question. am is missing something ?

Comment: there is no "xmlns:card_view" in your xml

Comment: @Williams do you get ClassNotfoundException ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I tried having android-support-v7-cardview.jar in my libs folder, doesn't work.  Tried having the gradle dependency, doesnt work.  Did you find a solution? Everything works fine on API 21 but on any other version i get the inflateException

Comment: I fixed my issue. I had set a drawable set as my `android:foreground="@drawable/ripple.xml"` which uses the API 21 ripple selector

Comment: Worked for me Thanks @MattWilliams89

Answer (score 7):

Let import cardview as a library:

Go to File -> Import -> Existing Android code into workspace --> Browse (Go to sdk/extras/android/support/v7/cardview) --> Click ok --> Click Finish

Your project explorer will now show cardview as a project.

Right click on cardview project --> Properties --> Android(Left Pane) --> Enable isLibrary (tick the checkbox) --> Apply --> ok

Now Right click on your project --> Properties --> Android(Left pane) --> Add (under library) --> cardview --> apply --> ok

Now right click on your project again --> build path --> configure build path --> Under projects tab, add cardview

You are done.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515471/2810231)

Comment: You are wellcome. I met this error before. I Googled and find two questions on StackOverFlow about this issue, but one of them have answer that help me resolve the issue. So i copy/paste to here :)

Comment: Actually I added v7 abcompat library to my project and thought that is enough to bring cardview too. Later I realised by your answer that cardView lib is available separately. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Don't forget to add the actual files in the "libs" folder to the buildpath and then check it in Order and Export. This is a must according to https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Comment: Very useful comment, I spent more than half day handling this error (but with recyclerview in eclipse) and finally I find right answer! Thank you, bro!

Answer (score 2):

(for intellij users)

- click in your project,
- right click -> open Module Settings
- import cardview from \sdk\extras\android\support\v7\
- add .jar file to cardview module
- click on your project and give module dependency to cardview
- now, click (+) button on cardview -> android -> at top you will see a check box (library module), enable it.
- click ok and close your settings dialog.
- rebuild your project and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Support libs that contain resources other than compiled classes (like XMLs) cannot be added as just jars.

Please follow the steps described by this:

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Let us now if that works.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem .
first you must add cardview from the \sdk\extras\android\support

1. Close the main project.
2. Remove the android-support-v7-appcompat .
3. Restart the Eclipse.
4. Add the  android-support-v7-appcompat .
5. Clean,To build the project.
6. Then open the main project and build all the projects.
7. The error still remains. Restart eclipse. That's it.

That works for me.

Comment: But now, I recommend you to use android studio

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Reference** : [Create Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView)

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this with the outer linearlayout.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... >
    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. 
In **Eclipse**, when you import cardview from directory \sdk\extras\android\support\v7\cardview follow the steps that are commented in "Adding libraries with resources -> Eclipse" in the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res 
 
Before adding cardview as library to your project, go to "Properties -> Android" of **cardview project** and **add the android-support-v7-appcompat library.** Don't forget check "IsLibrary".
 
Now, you can add cardview as library to your project. Clean both projects to refresh the changes.
I hope it helps you.