# How to disable the shadow around card view in android

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am working on demo application in which I am using the card view of the support library. By default, it is adding a shadow around it. I want to remove this shadow & should looks like simple.

I tried this (not working for me):

```
CardView cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
cardView.setElevation(0);
```

After doing these I am getting crash

```
11-06 15:12:17.018: E/AndroidRuntime(24315): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 15:12:17.018: E/AndroidRuntime(24315): Process: com.xyz, PID: 24315
11-06 15:12:17.018: E/AndroidRuntime(24315): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v7.widget.CardView.setElevation
11-06 15:12:17.018: E/AndroidRuntime(24315):    at com.xyz.adapters.RecycleViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecycleViewAdapter.java:85)
11-06 15:12:17.018: E/AndroidRuntime(24315):    at com.xyz.adapters.RecycleViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecycleViewAdapter.java:1)
11-06 15:12:17.018: E/AndroidRuntime(24315):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:2915)
11-06 15:12:17.018: E/AndroidRuntime(24315):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:2511)
11-06 15:12:17.018: E/AndroidRuntime(24315):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$RenderState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1425)
11-06 15:12:17.018: E/AndroidRuntime(24315):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$RenderState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1425)
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xyz"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Answer (score 168):

use this attribute in XML

```
card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
```

and remember add `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in your root layout.

**OR** you can call `cardView.setCardElevation(0)` to disable shadow programmatically.

`cardView.setElevation()` method and CardView attribute `android:elevation` will throw java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in platform before Android 5.0

Comment: This should be accepted as the right answer. I had the same problem and this fixed it.

Comment: i used `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` for namespace definition and it worked.
`http://schemas.android.com/tools` didnt work for me. Anybody knows the reason?

Comment: @CerlinBoss what's your namespace-prefix? `card_view` or `app`?

Comment: @Loyea : card_view

Comment: do not use card_view:cardElevation.
 replace it with app:cardElevation

Comment: @CerlinBoss, the tools namespace is for design purposes. It allows you to model actual behaviour of the view during design time. Example, you can use the `tools:text` property to set visible text during design instead of the `android:text`.

Comment: am new to android what is cardElevation means ?

Comment: @AhamadullahSaikat answer worked for me. I'm using Androidx libraries

Answer (score 95):

Try to put the elevation in Xml.

```
app:cardElevation="0dp"
```

OR

```
cardView.setCardElevation(0);
```

And check you are using the latest CardView library.

Comment: These properties are available in latest library but when I use latest then my app crash with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675682/exception-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-2-error-inflat

Answer (score 55):

use **app:cardElevation="0dp"**, don't use a**pp:elevation="0dp"**

Answer (score 21):

Just put this line inside your CardView:

```
app:cardElevation="0dp"
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 9):

You can have it in XML like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0.5dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >
   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

hope it helps you !!!

Comment: +1 - app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" - is required when it has rounded corners and cardElevation was set to 0dp.

Answer (score 5):

try like this may help you,

```
CardView cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
cardView.setCardElevation(0);
```

Comment: There is no such method `setCardElevation`

Comment: This method is available in latest library but when I use new library then I am getting this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675682/exception-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-2-error-inflat

Answer (score 5):

You should first add this to the your parent layout

`xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

then set the elevation like this

`card_view:cardElevation="0dp"`

Answer (score 5):

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
....`
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Please don't make a duplicate answers. How same answer can be for multiple questions, even you didn't change a bit. Even if you find similar question then instead of replicating your answer you should mention a link below question. Duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624954/android-4-4-remove-shadow-from-cardview/40168570#40168570)

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the following attributes

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0.5dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    >
   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Was going to ask the similar problem. Found this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is looking for kotlin answer then this worked for me

```
card_layout.cardElevation = 0F
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, only setting of background alpha with suggested elevation and backgroundColor hide shadow border:

```
 this.setCardElevation(0);
 this.setCardBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
 this.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

Comment: Thanks  app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent" worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Attenion:** Attribute outlineSpotShadowColor is only used in **API level 28 and higher**

```
app:cardElevation="0dp"
android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

CardView sets its own elevation during initialization, which will override whatever you set from XML. You should file this as a bug at [chek this](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3)

```
@Override
public void initialize(CardViewDelegate cardView, Context context, int backgroundColor,
        float radius) {
    cardView.setBackgroundDrawable(new RoundRectDrawable(backgroundColor, radius));
    View view = (View) cardView;
    view.setClipToOutline(true);
    view.setElevation(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cardview_elevation));
}
```

Comment: @Williams this is code in the CardView source - if you want to create your own CardView