# Android 4.4 remove shadow from CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-support-library

**I tried to remove the shadow from the Cardview.

I used android support v7 Cardview on android v4.4.2**

My layout look:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/include_profile_header" />

        <include layout="@layout/include_profile_footer" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

As you can see i used:

```
  card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
```

Tried so far:

```
android:background="@null"
```

But still you can see in the image i attached the top shadow that showed.

[image: CardView Shadow]

Comment: try to remove cardBackgroundColor @motis10

Comment: android:cardBackgroundColor not exist and card_view:cardBackgroundColor neither

Comment: card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"  remove this

Comment: But than it add to my layout white background. as you can see in the image i would like it transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove the shadow from the cardview in 4.4. Anything below 5.0 elevation does nothing so all the cardview is in 4.4 is an image with a shadow

> To create a card with a shadow, use the card_view:cardElevation
>   attribute. CardView uses real elevation and dynamic shadows on Android
>   5.0 (API level 21) and above and falls back to a programmatic shadow implementation on earlier versions. For more information, see
>   Maintaining Compatibility.

http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView

Comment: So that mean that i need to change the layout CardView to another viewgroup and add manually shadow just if i need?

Comment: But, its sound wierd. you say that cardview before 5.0 dont used cardElevation, maxcardElevation, cardPreventCornerOverlap,

Comment: @motis10 I dont understand what you are saying

Comment: elevation did not exist before 5.0 so how can that be used

Comment: If you want a different elevation look pre-lollipop you need to create your own image how you want it to look

Comment: So i can use @null in pre-lollipop? it will remove the drawable of the shadow?

Comment: whats the point of using a cardview if you dont want the shadow? without the shadow its just a white frame

Comment: I used it in some places but in one only place it should be without the shades i will probably use framelayout. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just add below code to cardview tag

> ```
> app:cardElevation="0dp"
> ```

and don't forget to add

> ```
> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> ```

**UPDATE**

Also try this put below codes in cardview

```
app:cardElevation="0dp"
app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
android:background="@null"
```

The `app:cardCornerRadius` should be bigger than 0(>0) otherwise throw exception

I'm using API 28 support library

> implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this problem by using a relative layout instead. Simply change the CardView value to a relative layout and you will essentially get the same result, but without the shadow