# Cardview shows shadow as margin in API < 21

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, androidx

I using androidx in my project. in android api 21 and above all thing is good but in below that cardView don't work properly.
please see images:
in android API > 21 :

[image]

and in API 19:

[image]

is `CardView` work only in api 21 and above?

my xml file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/searchBoxContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="search"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="textPhonetic"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textColorHint="#a5a5a5"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: this solved my problem try it https://stackoverflow.com/a/51221366/8696548

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line in `CardView` tag:

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Comment: Is it possible that work only in support library not in androidx?

Comment: using app:cardUseCompatPadding="false" show properly in preview in IDE but not effect after running in emulator