# cardview with rounded corners has grey background

Tags: java, android, rounded-corners, cardview

I've been searching for solutions for this problem for several hours now, and I know some guys have had this problem before me but their solutions just don't work for me.
E.g. `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` doesn't remove the grey background and the CardElevation is already set to 0dp.
At this point I just don't know what else I can do, I hope someone can help me :c

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="225dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorRedDark">

    <RelativLayout>
    .
    .
    .
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Maybe this discuss cantik help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624954/android-4-4-remove-shadow-from-cardview/51221366

Comment: @Abudl Ali thanks for your help but unfortunately I did not find the right solution for me