# Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView in android

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-cardview

below is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- item_feed.xml -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

logcat:

```
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at io.github.froger.instamaterial.FeedAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FeedAdapter.java:52)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4121)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3431)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:890)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-02 15:28:19.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.j
```

i also added CardView library in project using both jar and as a library project but still face this problem.

and i already tried below links:

[Error inflating class and android.support.v7.widget.CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494346/error-inflating-class-and-android-support-v7-widget-cardview?rq=1)

[Exception : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675682/exception-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-2-error-inflat?lq=1)

Comment: Post the stack trace.You are working on Eclipse or Android Studio ?

Comment: Either include the jar or reference the library project. Don't do both.

Comment: @JoelFernandes i said i tried both.. not used same time.

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace, including the nested "caused by" exceptions.