# Error inflating class CardView in runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to use a CardView in my fragment, but while I am creating the XML, I am getting a runtime error

> Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

when I change to that fragment. I have gone through the steps found on this stack overflow question ([Error inflating class and android.support.v7.widget.CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494346/error-inflating-class-and-android-support-v7-widget-cardview)) to add the .jar file to my project and set up dependencies, but my program still crashes.

I am using Eclilpse if that makes any difference. My xml file is

**`fragment_layout_three.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:text="Test" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

---

**`Manifest`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.pacificu.zeus.boxerapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<permission
    android:name="edu.pacificu.zeus.boxerapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="edu.pacificu.zeus.boxerapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCNkCxSPo3n2sUuDIZmP_W6LSHQGwsYR88"/>

    <!--Splash Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--Main Activity-->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case i have to do both the things add `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` as a library project and also add + check it's jar file in `java build path`

1. Go to File -> Import -> Existing Android code into workspace --> Browse (Go to sdk/extras/android/support/v7/cardview) --> Click ok --> Click Finish
2. Right click on cardview project --> Properties --> Android(Left Pane) --> Enable isLibrary (tick the checkbox) --> Apply --> ok
3. Right click on your project --> Properties --> Android(Left pane) --> Add (under library) --> cardview --> apply --> ok
4. **right click on your project again --> build path --> configure build path -->under libraries-->add jar-->expand cardview-->expand libs-->select `android.support.v7.widget.CardView.jar`**
5. **under order and export-->check `android.support.v7.widget.CardView.jar`-->click ok**

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much I've been stuck on this problem for much longer than I would like to admit!