# Android CardView And Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, android-support-library, eclipse-adt, android-cardview

I'm using Eclipse and have a trouble with `CardView`.

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardCornerRadius' in package

I already add latest **android-support-v7-cardview.jar** to libs folder and build path.

My **CardView** layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".activity.CardViewActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#84ffff">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test CardView"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also target sdk version in manifest is `targetSdkVersion="22"`.

But I still get same error.

Please, don't give me examples for Android Studio. It works fine in AS. But I don't use it for many reasons.

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449344/using-android-support-v7-widget-cardview-in-my-project-eclipse) ?

Comment: @hrskrs, yes of course. But as you can see it needs AS (1. Create a new project in Android Studio). But thats impossible for me at now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Instead of adding .jar file. You could import it as library.

[Error inflating class and android.support.v7.widget.CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494346/error-inflating-class-and-android-support-v7-widget-cardview)

Comment: Yes. You should import it as library. Library project has resources that cannot be included in jar.

Answer (score 1):

Try these (assuming you have have added `v7 support library` *jar file* to `libs folder`):

- In the new library project, expand the `libs folder`, *right-click .jar file* and select **Build > Path > Add to Build Path**
- *Right-click* the library project folder and select **Build Path >
  Configure Build Path**. In the `Order and Export` tab, check the `.jar file` you added to the build path, so it will be exported to project and **Uncheck Android Dependencies**

--

***Other way to achieve that***

Add this to `styles`:

```
<style name="CardViewStyle" parent="MyCardView">
     <item name="cardCornerRadius">6dp</item>
     <item name="cardBackgroundColor">#84ffff</item>
</style>
```

and set *parent attribute* of `CardView` to `MyCardView`

and remove these lines from `xml`:

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#84ffff"
```

--

***Also check if you have:***

- Latest `Android SDK Tools`, `Platform-tools` and `Build-tools`
- Latest `Android Support Library`

Comment: Thank you. But when I start project it again show the same error  "No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardCornerRadius' in package".

Comment: @Sever you can try my second suggestion, i edited on my answer, to achieve the behaviour you want

Comment: thank you again. But again "No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'cardCornerRadius'"