# In Xamarin error inflating class cardview

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have used smaple Code of Xamarin.Andoird.Support.v7.Cardview though i get an bellow error

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1:
>   Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494346/error-inflating-class-and-android-support-v7-widget-cardview

It seems the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **Android Support Library v7 CardView** component and add it again! Rebuild the project and it's done! you should not be getting this error now!
I tried the same and it worked.