# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I tried to adjust Material Design and add Fragment by using the **RecyclerView** in Eclipse.
Would you please have a check these logs.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.quki.error.secondmaterialdesign, PID: 17247
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.quki.error.secondmaterialdesign/com.quki.error.secondmaterialdesign.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at com.quki.error.secondmaterialdesign.FragmentDrawer.onCreateView(FragmentDrawer.java:72)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:842)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:830)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
at com.quki.error.secondmaterialdesign.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.recyclerview.R$styleable
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:434)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:404)
```

I think the reason for this error is failure for finding a recyclerview library.
And I did followed ways, several times.
Although it is CardView, I think it is similar to RecyclerView.
[Error inflating class and android.support.v7.widget.CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494346/error-inflating-class-and-android-support-v7-widget-cardview)

```
Go to File -> Import -> Existing Android code into workspace --> Browse (Go to sdk/extras/android/support/v7/cardview) --> Click ok --> Click Finish

Right click on cardview project --> Properties --> Android(Left Pane) --> Enable isLibrary (tick the checkbox) --> Apply --> ok

Right click on your project --> Properties --> Android(Left pane) --> Add (under library) --> cardview --> apply --> ok

right click on your project again --> build path --> configure build path -->under libraries-->add jar-->expand cardview-->expand libs-->select android.support.v7.widget.CardView.jar

under order and export-->check android.support.v7.widget.CardView.jar-->click ok
```

But I failed and get the same log before.
Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Undo those last two steps. Never manually adjust your build path in Eclipse. Also, since Eclipse support is ending in a bit over four months, you should have a plan for how you are going to deal with that, such as by switching to Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you i heard that we should swich to Android Studio. So I cannot use the **RecyclerView** in Eclipse now? Is there any way to add RecyclerView Library in Eclipse??

Comment: You should be able to perform the first three steps from your list, but for the `recyclerview-v7` library, instead of `cardview-v7`. I have not worked with Eclipse in over a year, but AFAIK it has not changed in this area.

Comment: Thanks for your helping ! I will use just ListView not RecyclerView.