# Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android

I have this error when I try to run my application.
Build is ok. Run makes errors.I tried to set multiDexEnable to true also butI still get the error..

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "it.prova.mine"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}



compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}

repositories {
  //mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
//compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//bug cardview
//vedi -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455867/error-when-       adding-cardview-to-layout
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
//Custom ProgressDialog
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
//Url Encoder
compile 'org.droidparts:droidparts:2.9.1'
//SearchView
compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.3.1'
//Retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
//jackson-jsog extension
compile 'com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog:jackson-jsog:1.1'
//
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
//java.time backport
compile 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.1'



//java.ws.rs.core
compile 'javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:0.11'
//javax.xml.bind
compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.1'
//javax.persistence
compile 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0.2'
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.2'
//javax.json
compile 'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4'
//jackson jsr310 plugin backport java7
compile 'com.github.joschi.jackson:jackson-datatype-threetenbp:2.4.4'
}
```

And this is the error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ7Pr.png)

How can I do? 
Thanks in advance